# Testing with java owner aeonbits

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, owner

I've been using java OWNER for property based configuration.

I've create a static method

```
public static final ApplicationConfiguration config = ConfigFactory.create(ApplicationConfiguration.class,
        System.getProperties(), System.getenv());
```

and I import the class everywhere I need conf.

Needless to say, unit testing is a PITA. I couldn't find a good way of override the values in the configuration.

I would like to avoid passing the config as a dependency in every class.
It adds a lot of verbosity and it doesn't make sense from a design point of view.
Same applies for calling the config factory in every class

```
ApplicationConfiguration config = ConfigFactory.create(ApplicationConfiguration.class,
        System.getProperties(), System.getenv());
```

Have you got any suggestion? is there a best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. You can create a class that provides the properties and all users use it:

   ```
   public class PropertiesAccessor {

      private static MyConfiguration mMyConfig = ConfigFactory.create(MyConfiguration.class);

      private PropertiesAccessor() 
         // No need to allow instantiation of this class
      }

      /**
       * Get properties for this application
       *
       * @return Properties
       */
      public static MyConfiguration getProperties() {
         return mMyConfig;
      }

      // for unit testing
      @VisibleForTesting
      public static void setProperties(MyConfiguration config) {
         mMyConfig = config;
      }
   }
   ```

   Now, everywhere you need a property, you can use this static method

   ```
   PropertiesAccessor.getProperties()
   ```
2. Notice that there is a method for testing, setProperties().  There are different ways to use this method.  You can create a test property file, load it in, then call the setProperties() method.  I like to have a utility method like this:

   ```
   public static void initProperties(String fileName) {    

      Properties testProperties = new Properties();    

      File file = new File(fileName);
      FileInputStream stream = null;   
      try {    
         stream = new FileInputStream(file);   
         testProperties.load(stream);  
      } catch (IOException e) {    
         // Log or whatever you want to do
      } finally {  
         if (stream != null) {
         try { 
            stream.close();    
      } catch (IOException e) {    
        // Log or whatever you want to do; 
      }    

      MyConfiguration config = ConfigFactory.create(MyConfiguration.class, testProperties);    
      PropertiesAccessor.setProperties(config);
   }
   ```

   Then, you can have various properties files.

   Or, if you just want to set a few properties, do this:

   ```
    Properties testProperties = new Properties();
    testProperties.setProperty("key1", "data1");
    testProperties.setProperty("key2", "data2");
    final MyConfiguration myConfig = ConfigFactory.create(MyConfiguration.class, testProperties);
    PropertiesAccessor.setProperties(myConfig);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> Needless to say, unit testing is a PITA. I couldn't find a good way of override the values in the configuration.

You can have [Mutable](http://owner.aeonbits.org/docs/accessible-mutable/) configuration objects. No PITA when you read the manual.

But there are better approaches.

Interfaces are super easy to test and to deal with while testing, when you know [SOLID principles](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrinciplesOfObjectOrientedDesign).

```java
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

MyConfig cfg = mock(MyConfig.class); // mock object
when(cfg.myConfigurationThing()).thenReturn("whateverYourObjectNeeds");

ObjectThatYouNeedToTest targetObject = 
    new ObjectThatYouNeedToTest(cfg); // Dependency Injection 
                                   // see: http://wiki.c2.com/?ConstructorInjection

assertEquals("expected result", targetObject.whateverYouNeedToTest());

// then you can also verify interactions:

verify(cfg, times(1)).myConfigurationThing();
```

The above snippet shows a [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) example, but there are plenty of similar testing frameworks.

Check what [Mock Objects](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TestsWithMockObjects) are, what is [Dependency Injection](http://wiki.c2.com/?DependencyInjection) and [Interface Segregation](http://wiki.c2.com/?InterfaceSegregationPrinciple).

> I would like to avoid passing the config as a dependency in every class.

If your objects need the configuration, you should pass the configuration to your objects. It's the way things should be. 
If it's verbose, there's something in your application design that needs to be revised. For instance, you chosed to have a singleton with a static member in a class, and that's [not very good](http://wiki.c2.com/?SingletonsAreEvil), especially for testing.

> Same applies for calling the config factory in every class

Calling the config factory in every class, it's a bad idea. Maybe you can split your configuration file in many component-specific ones. That's one way (my way).

But if you need a single huge configuration file (which is not my favorite approach), your config interfaces don't need to respect the same structure: you can have several component-configuration interfaces reading from the same file: it's not the best if you use hot reload, and I probably could do more to modularize configurations objects in a tree of nested configuration interfaces.
But hey, I did it in my spare time for myself and I shared it for free; if people do things differently than me and they need me to support the way they work, maybe they could support the development contributing good code or hire my time to improve it.

Sorry for the PITA.

Comment: Hi Luigi, thanks for your lecture. just a couple of comments
Interfaces are super easy to test, that's right, but I'm dealing with a static method.
That means I need to mock every single access to the property as you suggested.
Also it it not ideal during integration testing.
There are frameworks that handle this scenario pretty well (eg. Spring boot)

Comment: Obviously there are ways around it, but I was looking for a more elegant way.